# how to define cell excel cell reference as a parameter in SQL query on VBA?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, excel, vba

It would be great if someone helps on this.

I would like to provide cell reference from seperate sheet as a parameter in Where query I mean instead of a string "Arunraj S", I need to give reference from the range ("c3") of sheet1("PDA").

It is retrieving fine while giving the direct string through where query.

But It's throwing syntax error when I tried to change the query like below;

```
 query = "SELECT DISTINCT [Client Name] FROM [Execution Report$] WHERE
 [Employee Name] =" & Sheets("PDA").Range(C3).value
```

Here is my code :

```
Sub Pull_Data_from_Excel_with_ADODB()

    Dim cnStr As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim query As String

    Dim fileName As String
    fileName = "C:\Users\nizamudeen.s\Desktop\PDA Template.xlsx"


    cnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
               "Data Source=" & fileName & ";" & _
               "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0"

        query = "SELECT DISTINCT [Client Name] FROM [Execution Report$] WHERE [Employee Name] = 'Arunraj S';"


            Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open query, cnStr, adOpenUnspecified, adLockUnspecified

        Cells.Clear
    Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    Dim cell As Range, i As Long
        With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            .Cells(1, i + 1).Value = rs.Fields(i).Name
        Next i
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the query as a string. As it stands now, your query looks like this (assuming the name in cell C3 is `Tom Smith`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Client Name] FROM [Execution Report$] WHERE
 [Employee Name] = Tom Smith
```

Looking at that, you can probably see that it would fail in SQL because it should read (take note of the single quotes around the name):

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Client Name] FROM [Execution Report$] WHERE
 [Employee Name] = 'Tom Smith'
```

So, change the `query` declaration to:

```
 query = "SELECT DISTINCT [Client Name] FROM [Execution Report$] WHERE
 [Employee Name] ='" & Sheets("PDA").Range(C3).value & "'"
```

Does that fix the problem?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, Still I am getting error message as "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range". Please check

Comment: @Nizam I caught it the second time. Your `Range` syntax is also wrong. It should be `Range("C3").Value` (notice the double quotations around the cell). If you incorporate that into my initial suggestion, it should work.  Let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, an employee's name is a text string. You should be able to combine single quotes (aka 'ticks') with the double quotes wrapped around your entire SQL statement in order that you do not have to deal with quotes inside quotes strings.

```
query = "SELECT DISTINCT [Client Name] FROM [Execution Report$] WHERE [Employee Name] LIKE '" & Sheets("PDA").Range(C3).value & "';"
```

With *Bob* in Sheets("PDA").Range(C3), this should read as,

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Client Name] FROM [Execution Report$] WHERE [Employee Name] LIKE 'Bob';
```

I usually 'pattern match' with the LIKE operator but for all intents and purposes, LIKE is the same as equals.

Comment: Hi Jeeped, Thanks for the reply, Still I am getting the error message like "Run-time Error '1004'     "Application-defined or object-defined error"  --Please do the needful..